# How to model many to many relationship in code?

Tags: c#, model

I am working in a C# system where I need to model many-to-many relationship, where I want to build the models by hand (i.e. I don't want to use any frameworks).

I will walk through a simplified example of the system, and then explain then problem:
I have a library which contains **Book**s and **Author**s each **Book** can have many **Author**s, and the same goes for the **Author**.

```
public class Book{
     public string Title;
     public List<Author> Authors;
}

public class Author{
     public string Name;
     public List<Book> Books;
 }
```

Now if I want to *SELECT* books with all its authors; I would write a function in the **Book**s class something like this:

```
public List<Book> All(){
     List<Book> Books = new List<Book>();
     Books = //Query that brings all books and its Authors and populate them into the Books list.   
 }
```

Now I should be able to do something like this:

```
 Book boo = new Book();
 List<Book> books = boo.All();
 Console.WriteLine(books[0].Authors[0].Name);
```

But what I can't do is :

```
 Console.WriteLine(books[0].Authors[0].Books[0].Title);
```

Because in this flow `books[0].Authors[0].Books[0]` will be null(or the default value).
So I won't to make something semi-dynamic to and keep still keep in mind the performance from
the database server and client server perspective.

Hope I made my point clear enough. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why should an instance of *one* book be able to query *all* books together with thrier author? Sounds you´re actually looking for some kind of container that holds all your books.

Comment: Apart from this without your code showing how you populate the `Books` that belong to a given `Author` we can´t say you why it is null. So what are you actually doing when creating a new `Book`/`Author`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere, Mostly the query would join the **Book**s with **Author**s, I don't know if this answered your question.

Comment: "I want to SELECT books with all its authors". Every `Book` already has all its `Author`s according to your data model. Why you need query?

Comment: I have no idea what you want but this is what I've done according to your explanation. However, the output is not null. `var book = (context.Books.Where(x => x.Id == 1).SingleOrDefault()).Authors.Where(x => x.Id == 1).SingleOrDefault().Books.Where(x => x.Id == 1).SingleOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(book.Title);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this to mimic the database n to n relationship:

```
    public class DB
    {
        public class Book
        {
            public string Title;

            public List<Author> Authors
            {
                get
                {
                    return
                        BookAuthor.Connection.Where(ba => ba.Book.Title == this.Title)
                            .Select(ba => ba.Author)
                            .ToList();
                }
            }

            public void AddAuthor(Author a)
            {
                var connection = new BookAuthor(this, a);

                if (!BookAuthor.Connection.Exists(c => c.Author.Name == connection.Author.Name &&
                                                      c.Book.Title == connection.Book.Title))
                    BookAuthor.Connection.Add(connection);
            }
        }

        public class Author
        {
            public string Name;

            public List<Book> Books
            {
                get
                {
                    return
                        BookAuthor.Connection.Where(ba => ba.Author.Name == this.Name)
                            .Select(ba => ba.Book)
                            .ToList();
                }
            }

            public void AddBook(Book b)
            {
                var connection = new BookAuthor(b, this);

                if (!BookAuthor.Connection.Exists(c => c.Author.Name == connection.Author.Name &&
                                                      c.Book.Title == connection.Book.Title))
                    BookAuthor.Connection.Add(connection);
            }
        }

        private class BookAuthor
        {
            public Book Book { get; set; }
            public Author Author { get; set; }

            public static List<BookAuthor> Connection { get; } = new List<BookAuthor>();

            public BookAuthor(Book book, Author author)
            {
                Book = book;
                Author = author;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        List<DB.Book> books = new List<DB.Book>()
        {
            new DB.Book() {Title = "Crime & Punishment"},
            new DB.Book() {Title = "Karamazov"}
        };

        List<DB.Author> authors = new List<DB.Author>()
        {
            new DB.Author()
            {
                Name = "Dostoyevsky",
                Books = { books[0] }
            }
        };
        authors[0].AddBook(books[1]);
        authors[0].AddBook(books[1]); // constraint

        List<DB.Book> allBooksOfDostoyevsky = authors[0].Books;
        var dost = authors[0].Books[0].Authors[0].Name; // Dostoyevsky
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't think there is really a right answer for this question, but for me this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In traditional database design an n:m relationship consists of three tables:

```
Author -- 1:n --> helper table <-- n:1 -- Book
```

That's what I would do here, with 3 classes, Book, Author and something that connects both:

```
class Book {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

class Author {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class BookAuthorConnections {
    public int ID_Book { get; set; }
    public int ID_Author { get; set; }
}
```

... then make 3 lists that contain these classes, for example:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var authors = new List<Author>() {
        new Author() { ID = 1, Name = "Blah" },
        new Author() { ID= 2, Name = "Blubb" }
    };
    var books = new List<Book>() {
        new Book() { ID = 1, Title = "Some Book" },
        new Book() { ID = 2, Title = "Some other Book"},
        new Book() { ID = 3, Title = "Book 3"}
    };
    var connections = new List<BookAuthorConnections> {
        new BookAuthorConnections() { ID_Author = 1, ID_Book = 1 },
        new BookAuthorConnections() { ID_Author = 1, ID_Book = 2 },
        new BookAuthorConnections() { ID_Author = 2, ID_Book = 2 },
        new BookAuthorConnections() { ID_Author = 2, ID_Book = 3 }
    };
```

... and then join them, books on connections on authors. With a simple `Where` you can access everything you want:

```
var result = books
    .Join(connections, book => book.ID, connection => connection.ID_Book, (book, con) => new { book.Title, con.ID_Author, con.ID_Book })
    .Join(authors, temp_result => temp_result.ID_Author, author => author.ID, (temp_result, author) => new { author.Name, temp_result.Title, temp_result.ID_Author, temp_result.ID_Book })
    .Where(x => x.Title == "Some other Book"); //returns all authors who wrote that book
    //.Where(x => x.Author == "...") would return all Books written by that author
    //.Where(x => x.ID_Book .... or x.ID_Author would access everything by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the `Author` class be straight up (populate it in the constructor):

public class Author
{
        public Author(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            Books = new List();
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List Books { get; set; }
    }

In the `Book` Class, I also populate in the constructor. As a twist, I set the book property of each `Author` to `this`:

```
  public class Book
    {
        public Book(string name, IList<Author> authors)
        {
            Name = name;
            Authors = new List<Author>();
            foreach (Author author in authors)
            {
                author.Books.Add(this);
                Authors.Add(author);
            }
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    }
```

The code would then be something like:

```
    public void main()
    {
        Author hermanM = new Author("Herman Melville");

        IList<Author> authors = new List<Author>();
        authors.Add(hermanM);

        Book mobyDick = new Book("Moby-Dick",authors);


        string bookTitle = mobyDick.Authors[0].Books[0].Name;

    }
```

Any book created like this would be selectable by linq queries, or however you want to do it. Further, the chain would be infinite. In this case, I can pick the title. From:

```
string bookTitle = mobyDick.Name;
```

But I can also pull it at some other level like:

```
string bookTitle = mobyDick.Authors[0].Books[0].Authors[0].Books[0].Authors[0].Books[0];
```

In this case, having only one book written by one author, the result will be the same.

In the example below. I create a library with two books. And then I search for books by an author.

```
public void BooksByAuthorExample()
    {

    //Create library 
    IList<Book> myLibrary = new List<Book>();

    //Define first book
    Author hermanM = new Author("Herman Melville");

    IList<Author> authors = new List<Author>();
    authors.Add(hermanM);

    Book mobyDick = new Book("Moby-Dick", authors);



    //Define second book
    Author gamma = new Author("Eric Gamma");
    Author helm = new Author("Richard Helm");
    Author johnson = new Author("Ralph Johnson");
    Author vlissides = new Author("Johm Vlissides");
    IList<Author> gangOfFour = new List<Author>() { gamma, helm, johnson, vlissides};
    Book designPatterns = new Book("Design Patterns - Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software", gangOfFour);


    //Add books to the library 
    myLibrary.Add(mobyDick);
    myLibrary.Add(designPatterns);

    //Select books written by Richard Helm

    IList<Book> searchResult = myLibrary.Where(x => x.Authors.Contains(helm)).ToList();
}
```